# Setting __index of current environment in Roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

In Roblox Studio, I have a ModuleScript object that implements an analogous class to the one shown in chapter 16 of the 1st edition of Programming In Lua, as shown below:

```
local h4x0r = { }

local function setCurrentEnvironment( t, env )
    if ( not getmetatable( t ) ) then 
        setmetatable( t, { __index = getfenv( 0 ) } )
    end

    setfenv( 0, t )
end

do
    setCurrentEnvironment( h4x0r );

    do
        h4x0r.Account = { };
        setCurrentEnvironment( h4x0r.Account );
        __index = h4x0r.Account;

        function withdraw( self, v )
            self.balance = self.balance - v;
            return self.balance;
        end

        function deposit( self, v )
            self.balance = self.balance + v;
            return self.balance;
        end

        function new( )
            return setmetatable( { balance = 0 }, h4x0r.Account )
        end

        setCurrentEnvironment( h4x0r );
    end
end

return h4x0r
```

I then attempted to use the following script to access the Account class, assuming that all of the members of the 2nd do-end block would be assigned to h4x0r.Account:

```
h4x0r = require( game.Workspace.h4x0r );
Account = h4x0r.Account;

account = Account.new( );
print( account:withdraw( 100 ) );
```

The above script fails with the error `Workspace.Script:5: attempt to call method 'withdraw' (a nil value)`, so it must be an issue regarding the line where I set the `__index` field of `h4x0r.Account`.

Can someone please explain to me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `getfenv(2)` and `setfenv(2, t)` instead of `getfenv(0)` and `setfenv(0, t)`. You essentially want to change the environment of the *encapsulating function*, which would be stack level 2.

0 is a special argument that would instead get or set the environment of the *thread*, which is used as a *default environment* in some cases, but that does not affect the individual closures that have already been instantiated in the thread, hence it doesn't work in this case.